# Remove the Date in a URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-7.5

I am helping my marketing team optimize a Wordpress site by changing their permalinks from 'day and post' to just 'post name' URLs.  I know it is fairly easy to accomplish this within Wordpress but I am stumped in making the URL Rewrite Rule in the web.config.  We run our Wordpress application within IIS 7.5 on a Windows Server 2008 R2.  This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<rule name="Redirect from Day and Post URL to Post URL" stopProcessing="true" enabled="false">
    <match url="https://www.****.com/blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.****.com/blog/{R:4}" />
</rule>
```

I have placed this rule right above the following code block.

```
<rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```

I'm sure I am overlooking something in this rule.  Could someone help me out in figuring out what the proper solution would be for this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the rule you're going for to redirect from https://www.****.com/blog/1/11/2016/somthing to https://www.****.com/blog/somthing? Shouldn't it be {R:3} btw?

Comment: Yes I am going from www.****.com/blog/2016/11/28/something to www.****.com/blog/something.

Comment: I believe {R:0} is the current URL.  But I will give it a try.

Update: No luck on {R:3} or {R:4}

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for going MIA on this request.  I ended up convincing the marketing team to keep the date in the URL.